# Accept Dynamic Changes in ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I want to update the grid view textbox values in the database table.

I have Gridview, I have added on column with textbox, user is entring values on that text box.
To get that value on backend i am using below code, but everytime this is showing blank values even user have entered the values..

```
      foreach (GridViewRow gv in GvAmount.Rows)
            {       
                TextBox txtAmtToExch = (TextBox)gv.FindControl("txtAmtToExch");
                string Amount=txtAmtToExch.Text.ToString();
                objCurrencyConvetorEnt.CurrencyShortName = gv.Cells[2].Text.ToString();

            }
```

Below is the HTML

AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25">
                    
                        
                            
                                ' />
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                ' />
                            
                        
                        
                        
                        
                            
                                ' />

Anyone please suggest what is wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me your page_load code? And also show me which event you need to access the changed gridview data.

Comment: Can we also see you HTML?

Comment: This code only stores data associated with the last gridview row. You need to share more code if there are any further problems.

Comment: Below is the HTML code of Grid View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `this.gv.DataBind();` which will bind the data to the gridview dynamically.